# OpenCV and used color space

Tags: c++, opencv, colors, rgb

Does OpenCV deal just with sRGB color space? What about the others?

In some research, the part of color models / modes is not mentionned when dealing with the different tools of OpenCV.

As a start, when showing just the captured Images with OpenCV, are they as a start a part of the sRGB space?

Answer (score 0):

No, OpenCV can convert your images between multiple color spaces. You will find more information [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor).

Comment: Thanks. But first of all, the captured ones must be sRGB and then, convert to the desired color space?

Comment: Not necessarily. On Android, for instance, you would most probably get the image in YUV.

Comment: What about in Visual Studio?

Comment: use cv::cvtColor - transforms images between most colour spaces

Comment: @dr.mo Thank you, but it seems my question is taking another way.

I will ask it once again: As a start, when showing just the captured Images with OpenCV, are they as a start a part of the sRGB space?

Comment: depends on what source you are capturing from! try displaying them. if it looks ok then it's RGB.